# Error in firebug "invalid label"

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I have an error in firebug "invalid label"

Here is my code:

```
(function(u) {
    var getJSONP = function(u, callback) {
        var scrTag = document.createElement('script'),
        url = u

        scrTag.src = url;

        window.onload = function() {
            callback(scrTag);
        }
    },

    twitter = function(t) {
        document.body.appendChild(t);
    }

    getJSONP('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=twitter', twitter)

}());
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Which line of code is returning the error? A bit of explanation as to what this snippet is used for would help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/XjeTJ/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set url to u.
This section could be rewritten as:

```
   var getJSONP = function(u, callback) {
        var scrTag = document.createElement('script');
        scrTag.src = u;
        window.onload = function() {
            callback(scrTag);
        }
    },
```

Hopefully you will not run into any more problems there.
I have removed the redundant url variable. Also there was no line ending after the url variable. I have now put that in.